# Saving symbolic function to increase efficiency in Matlab

Tags: matlab, numerical-analysis, symbolic-computation

I have a lengthy expression which is calculated using symbolic differentiation of a rather complicated function. I now intend to call this resulting (symbolic function) in a for loop many times, and so I would like to avoid having to perform the symbolic differentiation step every single iteration, rather I would like to "save" the result of the symbolic differentiation, so that on each loop I'm just evaluating a function. Maybe an example will help: Here we try to evaluate the cosine of zero using two ways.

```
syms x
f = sin(x);
fp = diff(f,x);
fp = @(x) subs(fp, 'x', x);

tic 
for i=1:1000
    fp(0);
end
toc

tic 
for i=1:1000
    cos(0);
end
toc
```

Result:

```
Elapsed time is 3.654296 seconds.
Elapsed time is 0.007301 seconds.
```

Hence using my symbolic function is super expensive! Is there anyway to mitigate this expensive function call?

Answer (score 4):

Using the function `matlabFunction` increases the efficiency by a lot!

```
syms x
f = sin(x);
fp = diff(f,x);
F = matlabFunction(fp);
tic 
for i=1:1000
    F(0);
end
toc

tic 
for i=1:1000
    cos(0);
end
toc

Elapsed time is 0.037475 seconds.
Elapsed time is 0.004203 seconds.
```

Furthermore if the result of the symbolic calculations needs to be saved as a conventional function we can simply use `matlabFunction(fp, 'file', 'myfunction')` which will save the results to a function file.

Comment: This is a good approach, but it should be noted that the result of the function converted by `matlabFunction` will be calculated numerically, not symbolically (though from the question, the OP seems to be implicitly okay with this).

Comment: Do you want to evaluate to a symbolic expression rather than to a numerical expression?

Comment: @nicoguaro The reason for using symbolic expressions was so that I could differentiate a messy expression knowing I would get the correct result. I would then want to evaluate it numerically.

Comment: Understood, is symbolic toolbox of MATLAB good enough?

Comment: @nicoguaro For my purposes it was, I think for differentiation it can go a long way, obviously it depends on your own requirements but I would say it is useful.